# CSS Grid - Can't align columns when using grid-column-start and grid-column-end

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid, tailwind-css

I'm fairly new to CSS Grid and Flexbox so I would like your opinion on the best way to start with a 12 grid layout design that look likes these samples I found:

[image]

1. When using CSS Grid and I try to plot out the structure I'm having an issue aligning the columns of multiple grid containers when using `grid-column-start` and `grid-column-end` to make a column span wider (bottom container):
   [image]

   [CodePen using tailwindcss](https://codepen.io/jomsky/pen/MWJgoVm)
2. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong? Is flexbox better for this?

A tailwindcss solution is preferred but basic CSS is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue stems from the use of `grid-flow-col`. You're changing the way the grid is filled out. You've set 12 columns however by using grid auto flow column, it'll keep adding more as it needs to.

That becomes an issue on your second grid because while you have 12 defined columns and 12 elements, the first element is set to occupy 3 columns.

Remove '`.grid-flow-col`'.

Also, keep in mind that this: '`col-start-1 col-end-4`' can be simplified to '`col-span-3`'.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow

Browsers have some great built in developer tools for dealing with CSS grid. You can switch a grid overlay on which will show you exactly how things are going wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought that class was the equivalent of `flex-direction` in flexbox and didn't bother to check the actual style. With my second question though is this the best way to do a grid design like that or is flex a better option? One of the problems I saw with flex is that I can't use gaps yet so I have to rely on margins.

Comment: When it comes to dealing with an actual grid, CSS grid is your best bet. I usually use it to follow the grid structure of a design. Certainly better than flexbox for its intended task, grids. You'll still use flexbox throughout the layout too.

Answer (score 2):

You have to replace `<div class="bg-black col-start-1 col-end-4"></div>` for : `<div class="bg-black col-start-1 col-end-2"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

#### Instead of having two parents `<div>`, you can group the two grids into a single parent `<div>` container.

Instead of having two individual `<div>` containers grouping each column, have a single `<div>` parent container to group both of the grids together. Then what you need to do is add additional row to a single parent grid:

```html
<div class="container border-8 border-red-400 gap-4 grid mx-auto grid-cols-12 grid-rows-2 text-orange h-80 my-5">
  <div class="bg-black"></div>
  <div class="bg-red-700"></div>
  <div class="bg-black"></div>
  <div class="bg-red-700"></div>
  <div class="bg-black"></div>
  <div class="bg-red-700"></div>
  <div class="bg-black"></div>
  <div class="bg-red-700"></div>
  <div class="bg-black"></div>
  <div class="bg-red-700"></div>
  <div class="bg-black"></div>
  <div class="bg-red-700"></div>
  
  <div class="bg-black col-start-1 col-end-4 row-start-2"></div>
  <div class="bg-red-700"></div>
  <div class="bg-black"></div>
  <div class="bg-red-700"></div>
  <div class="bg-black"></div>
  <div class="bg-red-700"></div>
  <div class="bg-black"></div>
  <div class="bg-red-700"></div>
  <div class="bg-black"></div>
  <div class="bg-red-700"></div>
</div>
```

Notice that there's few additional tailwind classes added: `grid-rows-2` and also removed `grid-flow-col` class (I've also added a red border to make visual width comparison easier).

This will give this result:

[image]